# Best confirm dialog JavaScript library

Tags: javascript, jquery, notifications, dialog, confirm

I want to use a *confirm dialog* that looks better than the one produced by the build-in JavaScript [`confirm()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) method.

I have tried [Toastr](https://codeseven.github.io/toastr/) but found that the `confirm`functionality was a bit tricky to achieve with No/Yes buttons. It has to still be maintained and updated.

Thanks for all suggestion!

Comment: I use this along with toastr https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/

Comment: super. Was just browsing on that page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [jquery-confirm](https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/). They have a variety of designs.

Answer (score 3):

I think that one of the most beautiful API out there is [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/).

You can set up your dialogs as follows:

```
swal({
    title: 'Are you sure?',
    text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
    type: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
}).then((result) => {
    if (result.value) {
        swal(
        'Deleted!',
        'Your file has been deleted.',
        'success'
        )
    }
})
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]

You can even customize the CSS to adapt it to your project colors.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I completely agree! I've used sweet alerts and it's great. Also, they're fairly easy to reverse engineer and do all sorts of stuff. You can also style the hell out of it in your CSS.